# iOS 13 Tab Bar Layer attribute is missing swift

Tags: ios, swift, tabbar

I have added shadow on Tab Bar in initial versions on layer, but on iOS 13 we have to use Appearance that don't have layer attribute, how to add Shadow now.

Shadow on top like below image.

[image]

```
if #available(iOS 13, *) {
            let appearance = self.self.tabBarController?.tabBar.standardAppearance.copy()
            appearance?.backgroundImage = UIImage()
            appearance?.shadowImage = UIImage()
            appearance?.shadowColor = .clear
            //appearance?.layer this is missing now
            if let appearance = appearance{
                self.tabBarController?.tabBar.standardAppearance = appearance
            }

        } else {
        self.tabBarController?.tabBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
        self.tabBarController?.tabBar.backgroundImage = UIImage()
        self.tabBarController?.tabBar.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.0
        self.tabBarController?.tabBar.layer.borderWidth = 0.0
        self.tabBarController?.tabBar.clipsToBounds = true
        self.tabBarController?.tabBar.layer.applySketchShadow(color: UIColor(red: 15/255, green: 54/255, blue: 136/255, alpha: 1.0), alpha: 0.1, x: 0, y: 0, blur: 25, spread: 0)
        self.tabBarController?.tabBar.clipsToBounds = false
        }
```

Comment: you have used configureWithTransparentBackground.. you want your tabbar transparent??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set clipsToBounds False will do the magic for you.

```
//**self.tabBarController?.tabBar.clipsToBounds = false**

if #available(iOS 13, *) {
    let appearance = self.self.tabBarController?.tabBar.standardAppearance.copy()
    appearance?.backgroundImage = UIImage()
    appearance?.shadowImage = UIImage()
    appearance?.configureWithTransparentBackground()
    if let appearance = appearance{
        self.tabBarController?.tabBar.standardAppearance = appearance
    }

} else {
self.tabBarController?.tabBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
self.tabBarController?.tabBar.backgroundImage = UIImage()
self.tabBarController?.tabBar.clipsToBounds = false

}
self.tabBarController?.tabBar.clipsToBounds = false
self.tabBarController?.tabBar.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.0
self.tabBarController?.tabBar.layer.borderWidth = 0.0
self.tabBarController?.tabBar.layer.applySketchShadow(color: UIColor(red: 15/255, green: 54/255, blue: 136/255, alpha: 1.0), alpha: 0.1, x: 0, y: 0, blur: 25, spread: 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

UIBarAppearance has `shadowImage` and `shadowColor` properties. Set them as desired. Right now you are setting them to have *no* shadow. 
Also `configureWithTransparentBackground` means *no* shadow. So you are removing the shadow and then asking where the shadow is.

Comment: I want a shadow on top of Navigation Bar not inside and my question is regarding Layer attribute

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code in your `UITabBarController` class

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

      if #available(iOS 13, *) {
            let appearance = self.tabBar.standardAppearance.copy()
            appearance.backgroundImage = UIImage()
            appearance.shadowImage = UIImage()
            self.tabBar.standardAppearance = appearance
        } else {
            self.tabBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
            self.tabBar.backgroundImage = UIImage()
        }

        //Change These values according to your requirement. This will work for all iOS versions
        self.tabBar.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
        self.tabBar.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.3
        self.tabBar.layer.shadowRadius = 5
}
```

[image]

Comment: i have created demo check this it totally working fine.. https://drive.google.com/open?id=1EujM4QMY7U0xf-qH5uZmYB9uUYUAJT5E